# Unable to see Exchange tasks in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, exchange-2010

I installed Windows 8 on my computer. I am able to read emails from my Exchange account. I am also able to see appointments through the Calendar application. The two applications (Mail & Calendar) are native Windows 8 applications.

How can I see my Exchange tasks in Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

At present, tasks will require a full Outlook client, unless another 1st or 3rd party app comes out that specifically addresses tasks

the Mail and Calender clients in Windows 8 were not meant to replace the full functionality of Outlook in an Exchange environment as far as I am aware

Outlook 2010 and 2013 both work without a problem in Windows 8 (so far :)

Answer (score 0):

If you accept to use third party apps, you can use the following app:

http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/tasks-by-telerik/c66db128-7953-4da5-a87b-dc59758752ec

It synchronizes with an Exchange server, however it seems that you have to pay for the sync feature. I'm still in the free testing period and it works fine so far.

The following app officially supports exchange sync as well, but it doesn't work on my PC:

http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/tasktask-hd/b9f632fe-7360-4bc5-a845-21626d0cfa9e

Comment: Can you provide some of the details from the links in your answer? Just providing links isn't that useful if/when the links go away.